# Funnel algorithm : not possible with all convex polygons?

Tags: path-finding, navmesh

[image: Stalled funnel algorithm]

Disclaimer : yes, the whole map is not convex. But all of its subdivisions are ! (And that's what matters)

Hi ! I got A* working with nav mesh. Now I need to find the tightest path along the mesh path. While reading about the Funnel algorithm, I found an article where the author mentions that this algorithm can work with any convex polygon, as long as no portals are intersected.

However, while testing it, I ran into a problem : my algorithm is blocked. (See figure B) In figure A, the funnel can be narrowed, but in figure B, we can clearly see that neither side can progress :(

1 - Am I understanding the algorithm correctly ?

2 - Should I simply stick with triangles ? (I was keen on using polygons)

3 - Do you suggest another algorithm to make it work with any convex polygon ?

Thanks for your help !

Link to article : https://digestingduck.blogspot.com/2010/03/simple-stupid-funnel-algorithm.html (The claim about convex polygons is faaar in the comment section. (Ctrl + F -> search for convex))

Comment: That shape in your diagram isn't a [convex polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon)

Comment: All of these polygons are convex though. If the map as a whole must be convex the algorithm won't be really useful 

Comment: It might help if you edit to include a link to the article that you're following, but it looks like you're either misunderstanding the algorithm or maybe there's a lack of clarity in the material - when you hit that impasse, the path gets updated & the funnel gets reset.

Comment: As far as convexity, I didn't see any claim about that in [Demyen's thesis](https://skatgame.net/mburo/ps/thesis_demyen_2006.pdf) (starting on pg 52) - it was designed for pathfinding in a triangulation. It *may* still work with polygons (haven't worked through enough of the math to say), but convexity doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: I think you're missing a step from the article "and restart the algorithm from there (G)." It looks like this is supposed to be used recursively/hierarchically using a new starting point based on the last cycle?

Comment: Hi @Romen  We only restart the algorithm when one of either side is trying to pass over the other. (From what I understand. In fact, it works very well for me this way if I only use triangles) This happens mostly when you need to get around a corner. In this case, we are simply blocked because both sides are stuck. The more I think about it, the more I'm sure this algorithm doesn't necessarily work with all convex polygons. Thanks for your comment !

Comment: Something else that I have noticed, you have not triangulated your nav mesh the same way as the article. I see quadrilaterals in your navmesh, where they only have triangles. Your example of the alogirthm failing also seems to be related to checking vertices that belong to different triangles too.

Comment: Well @Romen that's exactly my point ! The author (and some others) claim that this algorithm CAN work with any convex polygons  I'm aware that I'm not using triangles in this example and I want to know if it's possible, in some way, to use any convex polygon instead of triangles, like some are claiming ! (For the record, I tried the algorithm with triangles only, and it works like a charm. I would just prefer to be able to use any convex polygon)

Comment: I think you need to eliminate some confusion with an edit. When you mention a "polygon" I am thinking of the overall navmesh. Obviously that polygon is not even convex in your case and the first comment probably understood it that way too. The subdivisions of the navmesh are also polygons (quads in your case) and they are all convex in your example. The comment you refer to that the polygons can be convex is actually referring to the subdivisions, not the overall navmesh.

Comment: Thanks for your input Romen. I added a disclaimer in my post ! I just found the answer to my problem elsewhere. I'll write it down a bit later to share it.

Comment: It seems to me that the algorithm would have worked if you traverse the edge that actually narrows the funnel, instead of the one that widens it in B. Then the rays end up crossing and have to restart from that corner (either works). Repeating the algo from there finds a solution (done in my head). So I think your example is not implementing the algorithm correctly by allowing a widening step instead of narrowing.

Answer (score 3):

Edit : After further testing, I found out that a special case of this kind is also needed for triangles in some cases. I probably just incorrectly understood the algorithm ? Maybe it's because this special case isn't often covered in other articles.

A kind person nicknamed winkio helped me on Discord, so I'll share what I understood from his answer here.

[image: Funnel algorithm with any convex polygon]

Disclaimer : to understand this, start by understanding the Simple funnel algorithm : http://digestingduck.blogspot.com/2010/03/simple-stupid-funnel-algorithm.html

To handle any convex polygon (and not just triangles), we can add a special case to the algorithm, of which I'll give an example at steps F-G.

I tried my best to explain (and illustrate it), but the special case can be difficult to grasp. I think it's worth reading if you want to use any convex polygon like me ! Somehow I was having trouble finding documentation on this very constraint. (Perhaps because going exclusively with triangles is the way) If you ever need more details, let me know in a comment !

Step A : Starting the algorithm. Both sides reach the next (first) portal.

Step B : Starting randomly with the left side, we try to reach the next left end of the next portal : this is narrowing the funnel, so it's good. ✅

Step C : Moving on to the right side, we try to reach the next right end of the next portal : this is narrowing the funnel so it's good. ✅

Step D : Moving on to the left side, we try to reach the next portal... but it's broadening the funnel, so we don't do it.

Step E : Moving on to the right side, we try to reach the next portal... but it's broadening the funnel, so we don't do it.

Step F : Ooops ! We can't progress on either side. In this special case, winkio suggests we "force" the algorithm to progress on both sides, but we must keep in mind the previous vectors... which makes a concave funnel, temporarily. Of course, this makes the algorithm a bit more complex because we need to keep track of more data in this case.

Step G : We try to progress with the left side. (Still from the first apex) Oops ! We're narrowing the funnel, but we passed over the right side. We must then add a new apex on the right side, on the last portal that was reached without problem. Because of the step F, we must also check if the new left side is also passing over the new right side, starting from the new apex. It is not the case, and since we overcame the "weird special case situation", we are back to a normal funnel.

Step I : Trying to progress on the right side. We can't, because it's broadening the funnel.

Step J : Trying to progress on the left side. Oops ! We passed over the right side. ⛔

Step K : Time to place a new apex. We also progress on the right side otherwise the right side vector will be (0,0). At this point we could stop because one side reached the goal.

Step L : The left side also reaches the goal if we continue the algorithm.